# PR 104923 Make clicking in scrollbars move by page, how and where do i set it to true?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In November 2020 VSCode got a PR #104923.
It made it possible to click in the scrollbar in the editor, to move 1 page at a time, in stead of jumping somewhere.
So the normal scrollbar click behaviour in windows.

I have searched the settings and online everywhere, but I have no idea where and how, I can set the parameter to true.

About the parameter itself:

In this PRT it says on sep 16 2020:
"I made the setting editor.scrollbar.gutterClickMovesByPage default to false"

And near the end it says:
"Rename option to scrollByPage".

So what is its name, and where can I find it.
Thanks!

(I use VSCode version 1.55.0)

Comment: I can't find it either and you can't manually add it to settings and have it recognized.  I think you should file an issue on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux, adding in ~/.config/Code/User/settings.json:

```
{
    "editor.scrollbar.scrollByPage": true
}
```

seems to have done the trick for me. Nowhere documented indeed and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/43564 still shows unreleased, while commits did got tagged with release versions. It took me some time today to figure out how to enable this.

EDIT: You need to restart VSCode in order to have this option considered.

To find the settings.json file's location: on Linux vscode, after opening the Settings, just hover over the User tab in the first line and it shows the file location. Probably that's the same on other platforms.
Option does not show in the list of known and documented options from UI.

That's bad that they left the jumpingbars by default instead of the scrollbars. When using a touchpad and not a mouse, that's really frustrating to have these jumpingbars.

Comment: I tested that before and it didn't work.  But then did a reload - which should not required for such a settings change - and it started to work!  So you should edit your answer to indicate that a reload is required.  Also, the setting will remain grayed out as `unrecognized` but works fine.

Comment: You are absolutely right. But you must also restart VSCode to make it work. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: In vscode v1.58 this setting will be made "official" and exposed to users.  See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/127788.  It will not display an error or require a reload.